# Why do I have to drop a snapshot in SQL Server 2012 to restore a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I never had to drop a snapshot with SQL Server 2008, but now when I try to restore in SQL Server 2012, I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operation cannot be performed on a database with database snapshots or active DBCC replicas.

Why is this necessary in 2012 and not in 2008?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you did have to drop the snapshot before the restore.  Here's the Books Online post about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189940(v=sql.105).aspx

In particular, "The database cannot be dropped, detached, or restored."

You might have been using a restore script or tool that automatically dropped the snapshots for you.  (My own restore database script does that - checks for snapshots first and deletes 'em.)

Comment: +1 also, if you restore over a different version of the database that has a snapshot, what on earth would the snapshot be good for? It would be completely unusable. Now, it would be nice if `RESTORE` had an intuitive option, like `WITH DROP_EXISTING_SNAPSHOTS` :-)

Comment: You had better have upvoted that answer and not just written +1, hahahaha....

Comment: are you kidding? That's my m.o. Make people *think* I like what they wrote. Secretly I am planning their demise. *Oh crap, is this real life?*

Comment: Now that I think of it, you are correct, just wasn't used to seeing that error.  But, when restoring in 2012, I got the error to go away when I unchecked something about `tail log backup` (not sure if this is what it was called) under options.